# Python finding out sets highest match

Tags: python, database, algorithm, set

I want to make a tool to help me planning the production.

I have table of 2000 products, and roughly 1500 different model plates (I am working in a foundry). Each model plate has up to 10 different (or same) models on it (models = products). When I get the order I break it down and end up with list such as:

```
product1 = 200
product2 = 500
product3 = 300
```

where productX is code and numbers are needed ammounts.

I'd like to make a tool that would scan through the model plates and find me the plates that have most of the ordered pieces on it. I would also like to do it in Python because I am familiar with it and I have wrote programs that interact with our database before.

Now I hope that I explained it well enough :)

Comment: Please provide more samples on what you need. Certain use cases

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: @ Artsion It's a bit hard to explain... I got some idea with regex that I'll try, and if I fail i will come back and try to explain better :]

Comment: You may find that making it so others can understand your problem means you actually find a solution yourself! Also, I'm pretty sure regex **is not** the way to go...

Answer (score 2):

"highest match" can be interpreted in two ways:

#### Item with maximum numeric value

Use `sorted` on the right hand side of each line:

```
>>> l
['product1 = 200', 'product2 = 500', 'product3 = 300']
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x:int(x.split('=')[1]))
['product1 = 200', 'product3 = 300', 'product2 = 500']
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x:int(x.split('=')[1]), reverse=True)
['product2 = 500', 'product3 = 300', 'product1 = 200']
```

#### Most frequent item

The Python [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is probably the data structure you're looking for. Insert your elements to a sequence, create a Counter from it, and extract the `most_common()` element.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l=['a','a','a','b','c']
>>> c=Counter(l)
>>> c.most_common()
[('a', 3), ('c', 1), ('b', 1)]
>>> c.most_common()[0][0]
'a'
```

Comment: I can't use Counter because I am using Python 2.6.2 atm.
I will look into it, and I am partialy on to solution, at least into solution that will allow me to forward data to excel and there manipulate it.
I am hoping to get some progress today if time allows me to code...